# usage of SEQ with a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I want to count number of rows in a file and store in a variable. I would like to form a sequence from 1 to count and save the sequence in dat file. How to achieve this ? I have used following code

```
var_count=$(wc -l < test.dat)
seq $var_count > var_seq.dat
```

It gives following error

```
seq: missing operand
Try 'seq --help' for more information.
```

Please help me where am going wrong

Comment: `seq 1 $var_count > var_seq.dat`

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: @anubhava I see you solved the OP's problem but supplying two arguments to `seq`.  So, what version of `seq` requires that?  The GNU `seq` is fine with one argument.

Comment: yes indeed gnu `seq` works with single argument as well. OP can tell us what version he's using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner would do

```
seq 1 $(wc -l <test.dat.txt) > var_seq.dat
```